# Redirect to a route if the request is not correct

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

My problem is to redirect a user if they try to access a page with the request method not defined in the 'web' route. Currently this throws a `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException` error:

> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: where this code come from ?

Comment: I just want to do a redirect if someone accesses a `GET` route which is defint in `POST` in the `web.php` laravel

Comment: have your exception handler handle that exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can leverage the Fallback Route function

```
 Route::fallback(function ()
{
    return redirect()->route('home'); // or redirect()->url('home')
});
```

Please note that the fallback route should always be the last route registered by your application
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#fallback-routes

Comment: Thank you all for your help the `fallback` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a route definition as below

```php
Route::any('/{any}', function(Request $request) {

    return redirect('/'); //or any other route preferred
})
->where('any', '.*');
```

Put this definition at the end of all routes.